# Find all polygons formed by intersections of lines

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, robotics, maze

I have a maze described by walls as line segments (no given order). Given a point, I need to determine whether its inside the maze or no. Everything is in the Cartezian plane(no discretization).

---

My idea is to transform the problem as follows:

Given some line segments in the plane, find all polygons with vertices in the endpoints of the given segments and with sides lying on the segments (you can see in the image below that you can't assume the sides will form a subset of segments).

And then just check: if a point is only inside one polygon, then its inside of the maze, otherwise no.

---

The solution I have in mind would be: hash endpoints and line intersections, and then look for loops.

Any other suggestions?
Thanks!

(ignore the colors in the image)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to find boundary (outer) polygon. That can be done by finding one point on the boundary and than traversing from that point by segments in one direction. If there are more possibilities to go than choose 'outer' one. Algorithm can be described:

```
find boundary point
find first direction to go and go to that point
while current point is different than fist one
  find next direction to go
  go to next point
```

First point can be find as point with highest Y coordinate, if there are more like that than one with lowest X among them. We can call it upper-left point.

First direction to go: first point is connected to other points and that points have <= Y coordinate, what means that connection segments are below first point. Choose right-most of them.

Next direction to go: current point is reached by some (incoming) segment, next segment to go is furthest away in positive direction from incoming one, what is same as first segment in clock-wise direction from incoming segment.

Comment: Why is finding the outer one enough? What if the point is inside one of the little ones? That's not part of the maze.

Comment: I didn't realize there are holes, I supposed that are 'ordinary' walls. Than similar approach can work. Make ray intersection from a given point and from first intersected segment find a loop containing that intersection (traversing in a direction). If that loop is same as outer loop than point is in a polygon, if not than it is in a hole.